# How can I fake cloud provider credentials in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-gcp

I am writing a cross-cloud Terraform module (for google and aws) which accepts a `cloud` input variable and applies it accordingly, for example:

```
variable "cloud" {}

resource "google_example" {
  count = "${var.cloud == "google" ? 1 : 0}"
}

resource "aws_example" {
  count = "${var.cloud == "aws" ? 1 : 0}"
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I only want to provide credentials for the selected cloud, not both - setting `cloud=aws` for example I get:

```
Error: google: could not find default credentials. See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

Is there any way to fake cloud provider credentials for the non-selected cloud, or do I need to implement some sort of Terraform templating?

Answer (score 0):

Every resource can allow a `provider` field, which tells it which provider to use. I think you may need to set real credentials for both providers, else Terraform will fail to initialise if you use backend configuration. Otherwise, set fake credentials as environment variables and see what happens:

```
TF_VAR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" # et cetera
```